# How do I insert icon in from createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently using Material-UI-icon and need to create the icon by in javascript.
Is there a way where I can do this?

```
import ThumbUpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbUp';

var thumbsup = document.createElement(ThumbUpIcon);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `document.createElement` should not be used in react.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.createElement` I would use as a variable or like `<ThumbUpIcon />`.

You can try the following:

```
import ThumbUpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbUp';

var thumbsup = <ThumbUpIcon />;
```

Then in the `return` part:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
   return (
      <div>
         <h1> First option: </h1>
         {thumbsup}

         <h1> Second option: </h1>
         <ThumbUpIcon />
      </div>
   )
}
```

Additionally I would suggest to read: [Creating React Elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#creating-react-elements)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Is there a way to create it by using document.createElement? Since I want to create the element if "some kind of event"

Comment: @James Can you please help me to understand why you need `document.createElement` for this? Thanks!